# I changed the symbolic link /bin/sh by accident

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sh

I am working on Ubuntu 11.1. The symlink /bin/sh pointed to dash in my system. /bin/bash pointed to sh. I accidentally changed /bin/sh to point to /bin/bash. Now, I can't open the terminal. How can I recover from this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the console:

1. Press CTRL-ALT-1 to open a pseudo terminal
2. Login as the root user (hopefully the root shell still works)
3. Fix the symbolic link.
4. You could either return to the console screen but it is dependent on the number of pseudo terminals you have configured, try CTRL-ALT-9 .... or you can simply reboot

Comment: I restarted my computer and now it won't start the OS (even in recovery mode)

Comment: Then what you should do is boot a Linux Recovery CD to the root shell, mount the root partition, and then change the symbolic link and then reboot to your hard disk.

Comment: @Bruce try adding `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel command line.  Then you'll have to mount the root filesystem to fix the link.

Comment: @AluísioA.S.G.: How do I do get access the kernel command line?

Comment: @Bruce On the boot menu, select the Ubuntu entry and type `e`. On the screen that appears, there must be a line starting with `linux`. Just append `init=/bin/sh` to that line and then press `F10`.

Comment: I ended up using the recovery CD and fixing everything. Thanks a lot everyone.